# Mathematica code for plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Regarding the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6497.pdf, I plotted the function of the Higgs quartic potential lambda(mu) based on the expressions (23-27) and even (47), on Mathematica. In fact, only (25) is enough to give the desired shape. I checked my code carefully and changed values of the Higgs and top quark masses within experimental errors, but couldn't reproduce the graph for lambda in Fig. 1 of the paper. The coupling is unbounded from below, while in actuality it should be positive at large values of mu. I'm puzzled as to this result.

Hope to receive your help. 
My Mathematica code:[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW87M.png)

Comment: This seems off-topic. Try asking it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please copy the code into your question rather than have it as an image.

Comment: you seem to be asking folks to go study an entire journal article to figure where you made a mistake (Or perhaps there is an error in the article, it happens.. )  Maybe physics.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestions.